# How to get the opposite of {?x} and {?y}?

Tags: dvisvgm

For certain applications, such as transformations of SVG objects, I need the opposite (times -1) of the current position's *x* and *y* coordinates, such as in

```
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g id='myGroup' transform='translate(-{?x},-{?y})'>}
...
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}
```

where `dvisvgm` substitutes `{?x}` and `{?y}` with the *x* and *y* values of the SVG coordinate system that correspond to the current location on the document page.

However, in the case of negative values substituted for `{?x}` and/or `{?y}` (which may happen in `beamer`-class documents), this leads to invalid SVG, as something like `translate(--12.345,-6.789)` (two consecutive "`-`" in the *x* coordinate) is written to the SVG file.

Another approach could be placing an inline calculation in the `translate` argument, such as

```
translate({?x}/-1, {?y}/-1)
```

but this doesn't seem to be allowed in SVG element attributes, as it leads to a parsing error in the Web browser.

Hence the question: Does `dvisvgm` provide a means for performing calculations on the substitution parameters `{?x}` and `{?y}` in the `dvisvgm:raw` special?

Comment: I guess, there's currently no way to negate the retrieved values without postprocessing the SVG file or tweaking the attributes with JavaScript. Maybe I can add something like `{?(expr)}` where _expr_ is a math expression that may contain x and y, e.g. `{?(-x)}`. Since dvisvgm already contains a little calculator, this shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: Thank you, @Martin, for your prompt reply! Yes, allowing math expressions in the way you suggested would indeed be a great addition to `dvisvgm`.

Comment: Should I open an issue on github, @Martin?

Comment: You don't have to but it wouldn't hurt either, of course. If there's a public ticket, I can directly link the changeset to it as soon as the implementation is ready and you get notified.

Comment: It is just a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to transform the coordinate space so that you don't need to negate the values.

These two transforms do the same thing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


===

\vspace{2cm}
aaa
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g id='myGroup' transform='translate(-10,-20)'>}%
xyz
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}%
bbb

\vspace{2cm}
aaa
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g id='myGroup2' transform='scale(-1)'>}%
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g transform='translate(10,20)'>}%
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g transform='scale(-1)'>}%
xyz
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}%
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}%
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}%
bbb

\end{document}
```

Comment: Phantastic! Thank you, @David!

Comment: @AlexG probably I should have used three different ids ...

Comment: Even simpler, using a single group. See my wiki answer.

Comment: ids are not required. The outermost group is given an id in order to be able to reference it (`xlink:href="#MyGroup"`) later in the document.

Comment: @AlexG sure but three the same isn't good:-)

Comment: Yes, of course :-).

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by David Carlisle's answer, I dug a bit deeper in existing SVG files and discovered that transformations can be concatenated within the same `transform` attribute. This allows for an even more compact formulation without additional group levels:

```
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g id='myGroup' transform='scale(-1)translate({?x},{?y})scale(-1)'>}%
xyz
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}%
```

Comment: looks neater:-)

Comment: Nice solution. If you call dvisvgm with option `-O`, the transformation is simplified to a single `translate` again.

Comment: Thank you, @Martin! This is a very valuable piece of information! I guess it will improve the rendering speed in the web browser which is crucial for animation-related usage. I will add `-0` to my `dvisvgm` command alias ;). So, `dvisvgm` parses user-provided raw SVG code not just for occurences of `{?...}`? Wow, impressing! Besides, let me thank you for all the incredible work you are doing on `dvisvgm`! It makes SVG a true alternative for PDF, especially for producing presentations. You even implemented a Postscript interpreter, something that even `pdftex` and `luatex` do not provide!

Comment: @AlexG that's O for optimise not 0 for nothing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In fact, I was in doubt as well, but for me, in my browser, it looked more like a zero. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexG Thank you for the great feedback. All the complex PostScript stuff is delegated to Ghostscript, so I didn't implement a full featured PS interpreter. The interaction between GS and dvisvgm is nonetheless a bit tricky.